# How to distinguish between signIn and linkWith in Firebase Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

In `onActivityResult` I'm trying to get the credential and perform a Firebase sign-in with Google:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task = getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            val googleSignInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
                val googleTokenId = googleSignInAccount.idToken
                val credential = getCredential(googleTokenId, null)
                firebaseSignInWithGoogle(credential)
            }
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            //Log Exception
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have created a firebaseSignInWithGoogle() function that is called to authenticate the user. This works fine. I have also created a linkAccountWithGoogle() function. When I press the button to link the account, the same onActivityResult is called. I can get the credential but how can I distinguish which method to call? firebaseSignInWithGoogle() or linkAccountWithGoogle()? I have hard times with this problem as I cannot see any relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll typically want to link accounts when there is already an account for the same email address.

So:

1. Call [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail) with the email address from the Google account
2. If there is already an account for the email address, link the Google account with that account.
3. If there is no account for the email address yet, create a new account.

Comment: That's the relation, an existing account. How could I not think of that? Thanks